# regex - preg_split getting inline script tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to separate individual inline script tags:

```
<script>
    console.log('hello');
    console.log('hi!');
    console.log('yo!');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("this is another inline script");
    var hi = "cool";
    console.log(hi);
</script>
```

Here's the pattern that I'm using:

```
$scripts = preg_split('#(<script>.*?</script>|<script type="text/javascript>.*?</script>")#', $str);
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>     <script>
        console.log('hello');
        console.log('hi!');
        console.log('yo!');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("this is another inline script");
        var hi = "cool";
        console.log(hi);
    </script>
)
```

While I'm expecting to get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>     <script>
        console.log('hello');
        console.log('hi!');
        console.log('yo!');
    </script>
    [1] =>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("this is another inline script");
        var hi = "cool";
        console.log(hi);
    </script>
)
```

What's wrong with the pattern that I'm using? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

If I use the `s` modifier I get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
<script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("this is another inline script");
            var hi = "cool";
            console.log(hi);
</script>
)
```

It manages to separate the 2 scripts but the first script becomes an empty string

Comment: `.*` does not match newlines unless `PCRE_DOTALL` is used.

Comment: hi, please view my update. I tried using the `s` modifier but it doesn't seem like its working either

Comment: `preg_split` removes the part it matches. See the manpage for `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just gonna make a list:

- `.` does not match newlines unless PCRE_DOTALL (the `/s` flag) is used.
- For [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) you also need the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option to not just get rid of the matched parts.
- In your case you better should use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead of `preg_split`.

And lastly, in anticipation of your next question, your expression did not match your source:

```
...>|<script type="text/javascript>.*?<....
                                  ^
```

In conclusion, better use something like:

```
preg_match_all("~( <script[^>]*>  (.*?)  </script> )~smix", $src, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str=<<<STR
<script>
  console.log('hello');
  console.log('hi!');
  console.log('yo!');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("this is another inline script");
  var hi = "cool";
  console.log(hi);
</script>
STR;

$split = preg_split('#(?=<script)#', $str,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($split);
```

I changed the regex to:

```
#(?=<script)#
```

and the result was:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(93) "<script>
    console.log('hello');
    console.log('hi!');
    console.log('yo!');
</script>
"
  [1]=>
  string(133) "<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("this is another inline script");
    var hi = "cool";
    console.log(hi);
</script>"
}
```